# How can I simulate a keypress of 'Insert'?

Tags: keyboard, macos, wine

I have an application that I'm running through Wine 1.6.2. I need to simulate a keypress of Windows' "Insert" key. How can I do this?

Some background: I'm running a game in Wine that I'm connecting a joystick to with [Enjoy2](https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2). I'm tricking the game into thinking that joystick actions are keypresses, and it works quite well - except for the *one thing* in the game that's assigned to "insert".

Comment: try the one above the 7 key on the 10-key pad like an x in a square. idk the equivalent if your on a laptop.

Comment: @Tetsujin On a laptop, yes. But I might be able to go get a Windows keyboard, would that help?

Comment: possibly, never tried it